# What does it mean "il veut me faire ma fête"?

Tags: traduction

It is in a song named Je Suis Décadente by Brigitte Fontaine

*Quand Ernest il veut me faire ma fête
Je lui dis « A quoi bon ? » très amère*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the meaning is the "argot" (French slang) meaning of "faire sa fête": it means "to have sexual intercourse with great vigor" (to put it politely).

Resources:
https://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/32570

Comment: I'm from France (as opposed to Quebec where it might be different), "faire sa fete" mainly means "to beat up", even though I understand the sexual meaning, most notably the second example, in your link, it's not the main (and surely not the only) meaning. Dimitris' answer should be the accepted one ^^'

Comment: En tant que Français, je n'ai jamais entendu cette expression avec ce sens.

Comment: I am French, grew up in France, and know Brigitte Fontaine's songs. I am 100% sure that "faire sa fête" means "to have sex with her" here. Read the rest of the lyrics and it will make sense. She's asking "what for" and he says "why not" which she says is too bad, he's only a simple guy: she wishes he could come up with a better reason to want to have sex with her. With the "beating up" meaning, the lyrics wouldn't make sense. If he offered to beat her up, why would she ask "what for", why would he answer "why not", and why would she say he's only a simple guy for giving her that answer?

Comment: For more references, Google "faire sa fête" and "baiser" ("to have sex"), you will find many links that would be too inappropriate to share here.

Answer (score 2):

> (Familier) Faire sa fête à quelqu'un, le malmener physiquement ou moralement.

> Gronder ou frapper quelqu'un.

> Attaquer une personne physiquement ou verbalement.

Example:

> Je vais lui faire la fête à cet abruti !

References:

1. http://www.linternaute.fr/expression/langue-francaise/18358/faire-sa-fete-a-quelqu-un/
   ;
2. https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/faire-la-fete/
3. https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/f%C3%AAte/33431#locution

In slang, as "faire sa fête à quelqu'un" means "to beat up somebody" it may have a sexual connotation in a soften, figurative way.

Reference:

https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/faire-la-f%C3%AAte-%C3%A0-quelquun.2342336/

**Update**

Thanks to native speaker @Greg for his comment cited below.

> Both meanings exist. It all depends on the
> context. In the song of Brigitte Fontaine, it rather seems to be the
> sexual meaning, it would fit with the whole tone and meaning of the
> song. For a song with the other meaning and a play on faire ta fête
> (simple meaning, ie, to party)/ te faire ta fête (ie to punish), see
> this: genius.com/Stromae-ta-fete-lyrics

Comment: But do you think it has correct meaning in the context above? I saw somewhere somebody had translated it to "make love" but I didn't find any resource for this meaning.

Comment: @MehdiPourfar I don't know to be honest. May be a native speaker could give more insight. In any case it would be better that you quote the whole verse of the song.

Comment: @MehdiPourfar You may be right. See my update answer.

Comment: Native speaker here: both meanings exist. It all depends on the context. In the song of Brigitte Fontaine, it rather seems to be the sexual meaning, it would fit with the whole tone and meaning of the song. For a song with the other meaning and a play on *faire ta fête* (simple meaning, ie, to party)/ *te faire ta fête* (ie to punish), see this: https://genius.com/Stromae-ta-fete-lyrics

Comment: @Greg Thanks for your comment. I added it to my answer. Really helpful native speaker verification :-)!